# Does anyone know Which Media player By default use in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

Please anyone provides me a name of media player used for ROKU.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Roku _is_ the media player!

Comment: I mean Which player use for playing a video in ROKU.

Answer (score 0):

Roku has its own media player. It does not uses any other or third party media player. You can add Roku Media Player as a channel and can use it to play videos from media servers as well as from USB(Provided you roku device has USB support). You can add this from below link--

https://channelstore.roku.com/en-gb/details/2213/roku-media-player